# mutate with gsub to clean out commas from a number - table scraped with rvest

Tags: r, data-cleaning, rvest, gsub, dplyr

I'm practising scraping and data cleaning, and have a table which I've scraped from wikipedia. I'm trying to mutate the table to create a column which cleans out the commas from an existing column to return the number. All I'm getting is a column of NAs.

This is my output:

```
> library(dplyr)
> library(rvest)
> 
> pg <- read_html("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rugby_World_Cup")
> rugby <- pg %>% html_table(., fill = T)
> 
> rugby_table <- rugby[[3]]
>
> rugby_table
# A tibble: 9 x 8
   Year `Host(s)`                              `Total attend­ance` Matches `Avg attend­ance` `% change in avg att.` `Stadium capacity` `Attend­ance as % o~
  <int> <chr>                                  <chr>              <chr>   <chr>            <chr>                  <chr>              <chr>              
1  1987 Australia New Zealand                  604,500            32      20,156           —                      1,006,350          60%                
2  1991 England France Ireland Scotland  Wales 1,007,760          32      31,493           +56%                   1,212,800          79%                
3  1995 South Africa                           1,100,000          32      34,375           +9%                    1,423,850          77%                
4  1999 Wales                                  1,750,000          41      42,683           +24%                   2,104,500          83%                
5  2003 Australia                              1,837,547          48      38,282           –10%                   2,208,529          83%                
6  2007 France                                 2,263,223          48      47,150           +23%                   2,470,660          92%                
7  2011 New Zealand                            1,477,294          48      30,777           –35%                   1,732,000          85%                
8  2015 England                                2,477,805          48      51,621           +68%                   2,600,741          95%                
9  2019 Japan                                  1,698,528          45†     37,745           –27%                   1,811,866          90%                
> 
> rugby_table2 <- rugby %>%
+   .[[3]] %>%
+   tbl_df %>%
+   mutate(Attendance=as.numeric(gsub("[^0-9.-]+","",'Total attendance')))
>    
> rugby_table2
    # A tibble: 9 x 9
       Year `Host(s)`                              `Total attend­ance` Matches `Avg attend­ance` `% change in avg~ `Stadium capaci~ `Attend­ance as~ Attendance
      <int> <chr>                                  <chr>              <chr>   <chr>            <chr>             <chr>            <chr>                <dbl>
    1  1987 Australia New Zealand                  604,500            32      20,156           —                 1,006,350        60%                     NA
    2  1991 England France Ireland Scotland  Wales 1,007,760          32      31,493           +56%              1,212,800        79%                     NA
    3  1995 South Africa                           1,100,000          32      34,375           +9%               1,423,850        77%                     NA
    4  1999 Wales                                  1,750,000          41      42,683           +24%              2,104,500        83%                     NA
    5  2003 Australia                              1,837,547          48      38,282           –10%              2,208,529        83%                     NA
    6  2007 France                                 2,263,223          48      47,150           +23%              2,470,660        92%                     NA
    7  2011 New Zealand                            1,477,294          48      30,777           –35%              1,732,000        85%                     NA
    8  2015 England                                2,477,805          48      51,621           +68%              2,600,741        95%                     NA
    9  2019 Japan                                  1,698,528          45†     37,745           –27%              1,811,866        90%                     NA
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difficulty here is that `gsub` is interpreting `'Total attendance'` as a character string, not a column name. My natural reaction was to use backticks instead of single quotes, but then I get a message that this object could not be found. I'm not sure what the problem is here, but you can resolve it using `across`

```r
rugby_table2 <- rugby_table %>%
       mutate(Attendance = across(contains("Total"),
                              function(x) as.numeric(gsub(",", "", x))),
              Attendance = Attendance[[1]])

rugby_table2$Attendance
#> [1]  604500 1007760 1100000 1750000 1837547 2263223 1477294 2477805 1698528
```

**EDIT**

Ronak Shah has identified the problem, which is that there is an invisible character in the name brought across from the web page, which means the column isn't recognised. So an alternative solution would be:

```r
names(rugby_table)[3] <- "Total attendance"
rugby_table2 <- rugby_table %>%
  mutate(Attendance = as.numeric(gsub(",", "", `Total attendance`)))

rugby_table2$Attendance
#> [1]  604500 1007760 1100000 1750000 1837547 2263223 1477294 2477805
```

Comment: There is some weird character in the name which you can see if you do `rugby %>% .[[3]] %>% names` copy the name from the console and paste it in the R script.

Comment: Ah, thanks @RonakShah. I looked at the raw character data to ensure the space character wasn't some high Unicode value, but didn't examine the rest of the string. I'll update to include your findings.

Comment: @RonakShah I did notice this. It didn't work when I tried copying and pasting either, but I hadn't realised that was the problem. Renaming it has worked perfectly. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The `gsub` function is to do replacements to all matches of the provided pattern. If you are going to remove all the commas with `gsub`, the correct syntax would be

```r
rugby_table2 <- rugby %>%
   .[[3]] %>%
   tbl_df %>%
   mutate(Attendance = as.numeric(gsub(",", "", 'Total attendance')))
```

Edit:

```r
rugby_table <- structure(list(Year = c(1987L, 1991L, 1995L, 1999L, 2003L, 2007L, 
                                       2011L, 2015L, 2019L), `Host(s)` = c("AustraliaNewZealand", "EnglandFranceIrelandScotlandWales", 
                                                                           "SouthAfrica", "Wales", "Australia", "France", "NewZealand", 
                                                                           "England", "Japan"), `Total attendance` = c("604,500", "1,007,760", 
                                                                                                                       "1,100,000", "1,750,000", "1,837,547", "2,263,223", "1,477,294", 
                                                                                                                       "2,477,805", "1,698,528"), Matches = c("32", "32", "32", "41", 
                                                                                                                                                              "48", "48", "48", "48", "45+"), `Avg attendance` = c("20,156", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                   "31,493", "34,375", "42,683", "38,282", "47,150", "30,777", "51,621", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                   "37,745"), `% change in avg att` = c("—", "56%", "9%", "24%", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        "–10%", "23%", "–35%", "68%", "–27%"), `Stadium capacity` = c("1,006,350", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      "1,212,800", "1,423,850", "2,104,500", "2,208,529", "2,470,660", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      "1,732,000", "2,600,741", "1,811,866"), `Attendance as % o~` = c("60%", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       "79%", "77%", "83%", "83%", "92%", "85%", "95%", "90%")), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               -9L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

library(dplyr)

rugby_table %>% 
  mutate(Attendance = as.numeric(gsub(",", "", `Total attendance`))) %>% 
  select(Attendance)
#> # A tibble: 9 x 1
#>   Attendance
#>        <dbl>
#> 1     604500
#> 2    1007760
#> 3    1100000
#> 4    1750000
#> 5    1837547
#> 6    2263223
#> 7    1477294
#> 8    2477805
#> 9    1698528
```

Comment: Have you tested this? It doesn't work, because `gsub` is interpreting `'Total attendance'` as a literal character string. The difficulty here is getting `dplyr` to recognize that you are looking for a column.

Comment: @AllanCameron I tried to reproduce the given data, see my edit

Comment: It looks like you have switched to back ticks. However, I'm surprised this works for you - did you have to rename the column to get this to work?

Comment: I did think about using gsub to remove just commas, but I was trying to use a regex that would remove anything other than numbers as practice. I used the same code as was used in the tutorial I was following. No idea why it worked for them

Comment: Oh, I just realized I mistakenly saw single quotation mark as back ticks. Thanks for the correction! @Allan